# orthonormal basis without gram schmidt

Tags: linear-algebra

I need to do the orthonormal basis without gram schmidt. This is the method I figured out after A LOT of trial and error. Are there any better methods than this? Its nice not to have to deal with nasty fractions like you do with gram schmidt. Are there any special cases where this will not work?

> Let
>   $$B = \left\{ 1/\sqrt(6) \begin{bmatrix} -1\\ 2\\ 1\end{bmatrix},1/\sqrt(3) \begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 1\\ -1\end{bmatrix}\right\},\qquad u =\begin{bmatrix} 1\\ 4\\ -1\end{bmatrix}.$$
>   a) obtain unique vectors $w$ in $W$ and z in $W^{\perp}$ such that $u = w + z$.
>   b) Find the orthogonal projection of $u$ on $W$.
>   c) Find the distance from $u$ to $W$.

$1/\sqrt(6)(-x_1+2x_2+x_3)$

$1/\sqrt(3)(x_1+x_2-x_3)$

Putting the information in a matrix.

\begin{bmatrix}
-1 & 2 & 1\\ 1 & 1 & -1
\end{bmatrix}

Reduced row echelon form

\begin{bmatrix}
1 & 0 & -1\\ 0 & 1 & 0
\end{bmatrix}

This is my first general solution. 
\begin{cases}
x1 &= -x_3\\
x2 &= 0\\
x3 & \text{is free}\\
\end{cases}

So the solution set is:

$$\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\ 
x_2\\ 
x_3\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
-x_3\\ 
0\\ 
x_3\end{bmatrix}=x_3\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\ 
1\end{bmatrix}, x_3\in\mathbb{R}$$

Solving for the $1,4-1$. This gives you a way to get the $w$ in $u-w = z$.

$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
4\\ 
-1\end{bmatrix}=1\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
2\\ 
1\end{bmatrix}+2\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
1\\
-1\end{bmatrix}+0\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
0\\
1\end{bmatrix}$$

You get $w_1 , w_2, $ from this.

$$w_1\begin{bmatrix}
-1\\ 
2\\ 
1\end{bmatrix}+w_2\begin{bmatrix}
2\\ 
2\\
-2\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
4\\
-1\end{bmatrix}$$

$w$ in $W$

$$w = \begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
4\\ 
-1\end{bmatrix}$$

$u-w = z$
$$\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
4\\ 
-1\end{bmatrix}-\begin{bmatrix}
1\\ 
4\\
-1\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}
0\\ 
0\\
0\end{bmatrix}$$

Distance

$$
\|(0,0,0) \|=\sqrt{0^2+0^2+0^2}=0
$$

Comment: You have a calculation error, the vector you found is not orthogonal to $B$. Once you fix that, you'll probably discover that $u$ is not in $\operatorname{span} B$ so your method won't work.

Comment: It would also help if you defined $W$ somewhere.

Comment: Why do you think that you might need to use the Gram-Schmidt process for this in the first place? $B$ is already orthonormal and the three problems can be solved without extending $B$ to cover all of $\mathbb R^3$ or even finding a basis for its orthogonal complement.

Comment: @amd like that with the w in W? My book gives a few examples of using the Gram-Schmidt process. My professor always likes to make us find a different way of doing things than what the book show.

Comment: @levap Can you point it out? I don't see the calculation error.

Comment: @cokedude: It's probably in the row reduction part. The vector $(-1,0,1)^T$ is not orthogonal to $(-1,2,1)$.

Comment: The row-reduction per se is OK. The error occurred during translation of the rref into equations.

Comment: Do you know how to compute the projection of $u$ onto $W$ without going through all that other stuff first?

Comment: If you're familiar with vector product you can use it to find orthogonal basis. If $\alpha_1, \alpha_2$ are your two orthogonal vectors the third basis vector will be $\alpha_3=\alpha_1\times\alpha_2$.